# How to change settings for truffle develop?

Tags: truffle, truffle-config

I'm trying to change the settings for my `truffle develop` node, but the values in truffle.js don't seem to work. Here's what I have there:

```
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.10",
      port: 95455,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gas: 47123880,
      gasPrice: 1000
    }
  }
```

Note that I tried to change the host and port values, but I still see `Truffle Develop started at http://localhost:9545/` when I start `truffle develop`. So I suppose the `gas` value doesn't affect anything as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ truffle develop
```

starts an interactive console that also starts a testnet locally on port 9545 for you with default accounts. This is for quick testing if you don't have any node running.

If you want to start an interactive console and attach to an already existing node:

```
$ truffle console
```

This will look for network 'development' in your configuration file, unless your specify the --network option. [See reference here](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/console)

Comment: so there's no way to change the configuration for the `truffle develop` node? like, change `gasLimit`?

Comment: pretty sure it reads gasLimit from your regular config file, https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-core/blob/1645fb5b57fdfd56869c64ae4f2c36913c9daf4d/lib/commands/develop.js#L85

Answer (score 2):

```
truffle develop
```

will read "develop" section instead of "development" section in truffle-config.js.

From it's prompt:

```
truffle(develop)>
```

we should know it use network 'develop'.

You can make customization in "develop" section.

From:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/develop/packages/core/lib/commands/develop.js#L69-L82

You can find available customization from "customConfig".

For some options, the name of customConfig is different from options.

```
    const ganacheOptions = {
      host: customConfig.host || "127.0.0.1",
      port: customConfig.port || 9545,
      network_id: customConfig.network_id || 5777,
      total_accounts: customConfig.accounts || 10,
      default_balance_ether: customConfig.defaultEtherBalance || 100,
      blockTime: customConfig.blockTime || 0,
      fork: customConfig.fork,
      mnemonic,
      gasLimit: customConfig.gas || 0x6691b7,
      gasPrice: customConfig.gasPrice || 0x77359400,
      noVMErrorsOnRPCResponse: true,
      time: config.genesis_time
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

If your on Linux, type `which truffle` I get this `/home/dave/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/truffle`
then open that file in a text editor, and find the variable called `defaultEtherBalance`, I found it on line 581569. Save and restart truffle develop!

Comment: you can also increase the block gas limit here, from the top of the file, i think its the first search result for `gas:`

Answer (score 0):

Now that our configuration is set up, we can now deploy to the live network. When deploying, we must specifically ask for the live network or else Truffle will fall back to the default configuration. To do so, we can deploy with the following command:

```
$ truffle migrate --networkid 13
```

This mines  Ethereum public network . Ethereum public network create then network id change .

thanks

Comment: I was asking specifically about `truffle develop`. When I tried `truffle migrate` with these settings, it, predictably, failed.